# Storing and Playing Music Files in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, html, mp3

Well right now I have paperclip storing mp3s and they only playback if I use amazon s3, which I'd rather not for now because then I am totally clueless on how to secure those files....

But now im rethinking my approach because I'm going to need to lock mp3s down and then give certain access to download. The catch is to me is that all users can play songs. but not download unless permission was given.

So my questions

1. Whats the best way to store mp3s and restrict different types of
   access at certain times?
2. Should I use paperclip? https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

The project is in rails 3.2.3, ruby 1.9.3. Uses a HTML5/Javascript music player. And lives on a Unicorn/Nginx server.

This may be used as our player, but I want to build one myself.... any thoughts?: http://jplayer.org/

Comment: This is actually a big issue for apps serving mp3/music..
You have to stream these mp3 using streaming servers..
like youtube/bandcamp does...
OR
you can just play partial content of mp3 like 2 MB of the whole i.e. partial content..on the app and server whole file when user downloads using buy/download link

Answer (score 0):

Learn and use Ryan Bates' CanCan gem https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

You would define abilities, like 'listen' or 'download' and in your controller actions, test whether the current user has the ability to perform the action.

Comment: Hey my project is built with cancan, rolify, and devise. :)
And it will prevent a hi-jack of a file? But im more concerened on how to upload and store these files?